# Getting server timeout while trying to connect to Cosmos DB with gremlin in Javascript

Tags: javascript, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I keep getting server timeout from cosmos db when i try to connect using gremlin 3.4.0 in Javascript (also i tried in .net core but still same).

I've been able to connect with old version of gremlin 2.6.0, but now when i update gremlin to 3.4.0 (also i read their documentation how to connect to db in version 3.4.0) i always get server timeout.

This is how i'm trying to connect (also i have ssl authenticator included):

```
const dbName = "dbName";
const collection = "collectionName";
const key = "key";
const cosmosEndpoint = "ws://endpointName.gremlin.cosmosdb.azure.com:433/gremlin";

const authenticator = new Gremlin.driver.auth.PlainTextSaslAuthenticator(`/dbs/${dbName}/colls/${collectionName}`
  , key);

const client = new Gremlin.driver.Client(
  cosmosEnpoint,
  {
    authenticator,
    traversalsource: "g",
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
    ssl: true,
    session: false
  }
);
```

This error i get in Javascript:

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT ...:433
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1083:14)
>   Emitted 'error' event at:
>       at Connection._handleError (C:\RDS\RDS.Graph.API - Copy (2)\node_modules\gremlin\lib\driver\connection.js:216:10)
>       at WebSocket._ws.on (C:\RDS\RDS.Graph.API - Copy (2)\node_modules\gremlin\lib\driver\connection.js:129:40)
>       at WebSocket.emit (events.js:197:13)
>       at WebSocket.finalize (C:\RDS\RDS.Graph.API - Copy (2)\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:182:41)
>       at ClientRequest._req.on (C:\RDS\RDS.Graph.API - Copy (2)\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:647:10)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:197:13)
>       at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:397:9)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:197:13)
>       at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
>       at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)

This error i get in .NET:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Am i doing something wrong or can it be because of db?

Thank you in front guys.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am getting same error in csharp intermittently. I think it might be because i am using serverless cosmos db instance? but I can connect to the db each time using gremlin console with no connection issue

Comment: @adeel41 Uh man this was long time ago. But i think i've didn't found the solution. I think that when i was having this error that there was no support for new Gremlin and CosmosDB. Maybe you can check that also.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to follow this [example js code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-graph-nodejs-getting-started) which works well for me.

Ignore the `package.json` in the project,just execute `npm install gremlin` to install the latest version of gremlin package(3.4.0)

[image]

Then run the app.js:

```
const Gremlin = require('gremlin');
const config = require("./config");

const authenticator = new Gremlin.driver.auth.PlainTextSaslAuthenticator(`/dbs/${config.database}/colls/${config.collection}`, config.primaryKey)

const client = new Gremlin.driver.Client(
    config.endpoint, 
    { 
        authenticator,
        traversalsource: "g",
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
        ssl: true,
        session: false,
        mimeType : "application/vnd.gremlin-v2.0+json"
    }
);
```

Execution log:

[image]

Comment: I've already tried that, but with no luck. I still got server timeout. I think its cosmos db that needs to be check, because it doesn't work with .net too...

Comment: @Hazaaa We may have a difference in detail.So, please provide your entire test code and i will try to test on my side.